# is it needed to purchase sencha license

Tags: extjs

I wanted to use Extjs in one project. I checked sencha site and saw that virtually all js resourses are under GPL3. It was amazing i have noticed that javascript source of Extjs library is perfect and much more well organized comparison with kendo ui whereas kendo ui force you to buy license in order to be able use their grid.

Eventually i could not conquer this misgivings and wanted to consult here to become sure enough that i can use extention js libraries for free.

thanks in advance for any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

If **your** project matches to GPL3 requirements, your choice is perfect. GPL3 assumes among others, that project sources have to be open sources, does not matter as free or commercial product you will promote.

If you do not want or you can not make the project's sources open, you have to buy commercial license.
Current pricing is now high, Sencha sells only 5-pack or more developer license, brutto ~ **$5000**.